# Given $f(x)$ and $g(x)$, find $(fg)(x)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, solution-verification

I've attempted to solve the problem below, and here is what I got for a solution:

> Given $f(x)=x^2-9$ and $g(x)=x^2+3x-1$, find $(fg)(x).$

$$
\begin{align}
(fg)(x)&=(x^2-9)(x^2+3x-1)\\
&=x^4+3x^3-x^2-9x^2-27x+9\\
&=x^4+3x^3-10x^2-27x+9
\end{align}
$$

**Have I done this correctly?**

I am wondering if I should have factored $(x^2-9)$ before multiplying, but I'm not sure if it would have made a difference.

Comment: You are correct!

Comment: Converting to LaTeX...

Comment: Thanks for the edit @FundThmCalculus . I'm still not super confident with LaTeX.

Comment: @McB, not a problem. Once one of the higher-ranked people reviews the edit, it will appear. :) EDIT: Approved! :)

Comment: Sometimes notation $fg$ is used as an abbreviation for composition. Then $(fg)(x):=f(g(x))$. I hope that this is not the case here.

Comment: @drhab I don't believe that is the case here; different notation has been clearly assigned to composition in the course I am taking. Thanks for the good point though.

Comment: I am relieved by your comment.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are correct. If I know what you are saying, you are right that it wouldn't matter. The factored form is $(x+3)(x-3)(x^2+3x-1)$.